# For loop in a list generated by input only returning first item

Tags: python, list, for-loop

After getting user input, printing shopping_list gives all the inputs, however my for loop function only gives back the first input. Does anyone know why the for loop isn't returning all of the input items from the list?

```
shopping_list = []

a = input("This is shopping bot. Tell me one thing you want to buy: ")
b = input("And then... ")

def g():
    for i in shopping_list:
        return (i)

shopping_list.extend(a,b)
print(shopping_list)

print("Here's your shopping list : \n",g())
```

Comment: your g() function returns i , that is only one value  if you want to return all just print shopping list and get rid of the g() function

Comment: It seems like, you need to look for join method. `print(", ".join(shopping_list))`

Answer (score 1):

You used `return` which exits the function and returns item `i`, so your loop exits during its first iteration.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve so I can't recommend anything

Comment: Looking to print the contents of the list generated from user input

Comment: then you should probably use join like suggested by several people here. if you insist on having a function call you can have the contents of `g` be: `return ",  ".join(shopping_list)`

Answer (score 1):

A function call is terminated after it encounters a `return` statement. The reason this is happening is because inside your `for` loop you are using a `return` statement. It will exit after returning the first element. If you reverse your list and use it as an input to the function you'll get the last element of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

A better aproach to this problem would be something like this:

```
shopping_list = input("This is shopping bot. List things you want to buy: ").split(',')

print("Here's your shopping list: \n", '\n'.join(shopping_list))
```

This way user can input `n` elements.

Comment: Just make sure you list elements with comma separating each item. Otherwise you'll get an error because it's not catching them.